# Rails Models: how would you create a pre-defined set of attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes, model

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design a rails model. For purposes of the example, let's say I'm building a database of characters, which may have several different fixed attributes. For instance:

```
Character
- Morality (may be "Good" or "Evil")
- Genre (may be "Action", "Suspense", or "Western")
- Hair Color (may be "Blond", "Brown", or "Black")
```

... and so on.

So, for the Character model there are several attributes where I want to basically have a fixed list of possible selections.

I want users to be able to create a character, and in the form I want them to pick one from each of the available options. I also want to be able to let users search using each of these attributes... ( ie, "Show me Characters which are 'Good', from the 'Suspense' genre, and have 'Brown' hair).

I can think of a couple ways to do this...

---

**1: Create a string for each attribute and validate limited input.**

In this case I would define an string column "Morality" on the character table, then have a class constant with the options specified in it, and then validate against that class constant.

Finding good characters would be like `Character.where(:morality=>'Good')`.

This is nice and simple, the downside is if I wanted to add some more detail to the attribute, for instance to have a description of "Good" and "Evil", and a page where users could view all the characters for a given morality.

**2: Create a model for each attribute**

In this case `Character belongs_to Morality`, there would be a `Morality` model and a `moralities` table with two records in it: `Morality id:1, name:Good` etc.

Finding good characters would be like `Morality.find_by_name('Good').characters`... or
`Character.where(:morality=> Morality.find(1)`.

This works fine, but it means you have several tables that exist only to hold a small number of predefined attributes.

**3: Create a STI model for attributes**

In this case I could do the same as #2, except create a general "CharacterAttributes" table and then subclass it for "MoralityAttribute" and "GenreAttribute" etc. This makes only one table for the many attributes, otherwise it seems about the same as idea #2.

---

So, those are the three ways I can think of to solve this problem.

**My question is, how would you implement this, and why?**

Would you use one of the approaches above, and if so which one? Would you do something different? I'd especially be interested to hear performance considerations for the approach you would take. I know this is a broad question, thank you for any input.

**EDIT:**
I'm adding a Bounty of 250 (more than 10% of my reputation!!) on this question because I could really use some more extended discussion of pros / cons / options. I'll give upvotes to anyone who weighs in with something constructive, and if someone can give me a really solid example of which approach they take and WHY it'll be worth +250.

I'm really agonizing over the design of this aspect of my app and it's now time to implement it. Thanks in advance for any helpful discussion!!

---

**FINAL NOTE:**

Thank you all for your thoughtful and interesting answers, all of them are good and were very helpful to me. In the end (coming in right before the bounty expired!) I really appreciated Blackbird07's answer. While everyone offered good suggestions, for me personally his was the most useful. I wasn't really aware of the idea of an enum before, and since looking into it I find it solves many of the issues I've been having in my app. I would encourage everyone who discovers this question to read all the answers, there are many good approaches offered.

Comment: I would go for model-per-attribute for modularity purposes, unless they're binary (gender, etc.)

Comment: See note regarding added Bounty above. Tamer's example is a good answer, but I could really use some more discussion of different approaches people have taken and **WHY** one might work better than another in different circumstances. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put simply, you're asking how to enumerate ActiveRecord attributes. There are a lot of discussions around the web and even on SO for using enums in rails applications, e.g. [here](http://thinkinginrails.com/2010/04/more-on-using-enums-for-constant-data-in-rails/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282710/how-do-i-describe-an-enumeration-column-in-a-rails-3-migration) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428821/using-an-enum-as-an-attribute-argument) to name a few.

I never used one of the many gems there are for enums, **but [active_enum gem](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum) sounds particularly suited for your use case**. It doesn't have the downsides of an activerecord-backed attribute set and makes maintenance of attribute values a piece of cake. It even comes with form helpers for formtastic or simple form (which I assume could help you for attribute selection in your character search).

Comment: This looks great! One question: does an enum allow selecting multiple values? Ie can I have an attribute like: "Habits" with one or more possible values using an enum? If so, how?

Comment: Hi Andrew, the nature of an enum is to have exactly one value of a set of predefined values. So if you require your model to possibly have multiple values of the set applied, then this solution won't work for you, I'm afraid. On the other hand, it would theoretically be possible to define a serialized attribute and store a hash or array of enums in it.

Comment: Ok, this is still a great option -- I didn't even realize what an enum was before this, so thank you very much for calling this to my attention!

Answer (score 25):

I assume that you are going to have more than a few of these multiple-choice attributes, and would like to keep things tidy.

I would recommend the **store it in the database** approach **only** if you want to **modify the choices** at runtime, otherwise it would quickly become a performance hit; If a model has three such attributes, it would take four database calls instead of one to retreive it.

**Hardcoding the choices** into validations is a fast way, but it becomes **tedious** to maintain. You have to make sure that every similar validator and drop-down list etc. use matching values. And it becomes quite hard and cumbersome if the list becomes long. It's only practical if you have 2-5 choices that really won't change much, like `male, female, unspecified`

What I'd **recommend** is that you use a **configuration YAML file**. This way you can have a single **tidy** document for all your choices

```
# config/choices.yml

morality:
  - Good
  - Evil
genre:
  - Action
  - Suspense
  - Western
hair_color:
  - Blond
  - Brown
  - Black
```

Then you can load this file into a constant as a `Hash`

```
# config/initializers/load_choices.rb

Choices = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/choices.yml")
```

Use it in your models;

```
# app/models/character.rb

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :morality, in: Choices['morality']
  validates_inclusion_of :genre, in: Choices['genre']
  # etc…
end
```

Use them in views;

```
<%= select @character, :genre, Choices['genre'] %>
```

etc…

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and hits on a lot of the things I'm already doing. Question: How would you handle this with a "select all that apply" attribute versus a "select one or the other" attribute?

Comment: I'd make it a [serialized](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize) array in a text column. Do you want details?

Comment: Don't you run into problems searching serialized arrays? For instance, if you had an attribute called "appearances" with options "book, comic, movie, game" -- and possibly many applied, how would you search for characters that appeared in movies?

Comment: The serialized form is YAML as well, so you may do something like `Character.where("appearances LIKE %book%")`

Answer (score 2):

If a change in any of these attributes would be strongly tied to a change in the code (ie: When a new Hair Color is introduced, a new page is created or a new action is implemented), then I'd say add them as a string hash (option 1). You could store them in the Character model as a finalized hashes with other meta-data.

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  MORALITY = {:good => ['Good' => 'Person is being good'], :evil => ['Evil' => 'Person is being Evil']}
  ...
end

Character.where(:morality => Character::MORALITY[:good][0])
```

Edit to add the code from comment:

Given `Character::MORALITY = {:good => {:name => 'Good', :icon => 'good.png'}, ...`

```
- Character::MORALITY.each do |k,v| 
  = check_box_tag('morality', k.to_s)
  = image_tag(v[:icon], :title => v[:name])

= Character::MORALITY[@a_character.morality.to_sym][:name]
```

Comment: Tamer, this looks interesting. So, if you wanted to have icons associated with these, could you do something like: `Morality = {:good=>{:name=>'Good',:icon=>'good_guy.png'} ... }` and then iterate through in a view using `Character::Morality.each {|m| image_tag( m[:icon], :title => m[:name] ) }` Does that sound like it would work?   Also, what kind of form input would you use to let people pick one of these options?

Comment: Something like:
    - Character::MORALITY.each do |k,v| 
      = check_box_tag('morality', k.to_s)
      = image_tag(v[:icon], :title => v[:name])


In this case the user picks the keys in those hashes ('good', 'suspense') as the values to store in the relevant fields (make sure the fields are indexed for better performance). As you retrieve the values, you could do something like:

= Character::MORALITY[@some_character.morality.to_sym][:name] #Good
You can wrap that in a generic helper, and watch out for unassigned values.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use a NoSQL database such as MongoDB.

MongoDB support embedded documents. An embedded document is saved in the same entry as the parent. So it is very fast for retrieval, it is like accessing a common field. But embed documents can be very rich.

```
class Character
   include Mongoid::Document

   embeds_one :morality
   embeds_many :genres
   embeds_one :hair_colour

   index 'morality._type'
   index 'genres._type'         
end         

class Morality
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, default: 'undefined'
   field :description, default: ''
   embedded_in :character      
end

class Evil < Morality
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, default: 'Evil'
   field :description, 
          default: 'Evil characters try to harm people when they can'
   field :another_field
end

class Good < Morality
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, default: 'Good'
   field :description, 
          default: 'Good characters try to help people when they can'
   field :a_different_another_field
end
```

Operations:

```
character = Character.create(
          morality: Evil.new, 
          genres: [Action.new, Suspense.new], 
          hair_colour: Yellow.new )

# very very fast operations because it is accessing an embed document
character.morality.name      
character.morality.description

# Very fast operation because you can build an index on the _type field.
Character.where('morality._type' => 'Evil').execute.each { |doc| p doc.morality }

# Matches all characters that have a genre of type Western.
Character.where('genres._type' => 'Western')

# Matches all characters that have a genre of type Western or Suspense.
Character.any_in('genres._type' => ['Western','Suspense'])
```

This approach has the advantage that adding a new type of Morality is just adding a new Model that inherits from Morality. You don't need to change anything else.

Adding new Morality types do not have any performance penalty. The index take care of maintaing fast query operations.

Accessing the embed fields is very fast. It is like accessing a common field.

The advantage of this approach over just a YML file is that you can have very rich embed documents. Each of these documents can perfectly grow to your needs. Need a description field? add it.

But I would combine the two options. The YML file could be very useful for having a reference that you can use in Select boxes for example. While having embeds document gives you the desired flexibility.

Comment: This is very interesting, I've never worked with Mongo before. I have a few questions: The example in this question is contrived, but in reality I'm added new functionality to an existing app which runs on ActiveRecord. (1) Is it possible to use Mongo side-by-side with ActiveRecord -- ie so I don't have to redo the rest of the app that doesn't need this functionality? (2) Either way, can you point me to any resources about how to migrate from ActiveRecord to Mongoid? I would need to think about what that would involve. This definitely looks like a good way to do a new app.

Comment: @Andrew: Mongoid is an ODM for the MongoDB that implements active record. So it is quite straightforward to migrate from active record to Mongoid. You can use both at the same time, just include Mongoid::Document when you want to use Mongoid. The official documentation is here http://mongoid.org/ or here http://high-river-344.heroku.com/

Comment: @Andrew: Migrating to Mongoid from Active record no not involve much changes in code. The real thing will be to migrate the existing data in the database.

Comment: @Andrew: This is a very interesting interview about the guys at Craiglist, which migrated a massive SQL infrastructure to MongoDB http://www.10gen.com/presentation/mongosf2011/craigslist

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow 2 principles: DRY, developers happiness over code complicate.

First of all, the predefined Character data will be in the model as a constant.
The second is about validation, we will do a bit metaprogramming here, as well as searching with scopes.

```
#models/character.rb
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  DEFAULT_VALUES = {:morality => ['Good', 'Evil'], :genre => ['Action', 'Suspense', 'Western'], :hair_color => ['Blond', 'Brown', 'Black']}

  include CharacterScopes
end

#models/character_scopes.rb
module CharacterScopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do

      DEFAULT_VALUES.each do |k,v|
        validates_inclusion_of k.to_sym, :in => v

        define_method k do
          where(k.to_sym).in(v)
        end
        # OR 
        scope k.to_sym, lambda {:where(k.to_sym).in(v)}
      end

    end
  end
end


#app/views/characters/form.html
<% Character::DEFAULT_VALUES.each do |k,v] %>
  <%= select_tag :k, options_from_collection_for_select(v) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple values case, one option is to use bit fields as implemented in the [FlagShihTzu](https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu) gem. This stores a number of flags in a single integer field.