# What is the way to limit a model attribute to a list of values in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, model, attributes

I'm starting to build out the models in my Rails app and I'm wondering what the various ways are to define a table column that should be limited to a list of values?

For instance, a `title` column of a `clients` table. If I only want 3 values:

- Mr
- Mrs
- Other

What are the various approaches to achieving this with the pros and cons?

**Option A**

Traditionally, I've followed Third Normal Form (3NF) and created a `client_titles` table and using associations, but that seems overkill as I don't want to have to go and create models for that table, as it's more code to maintain than seems necessary.

- Pros ?
- Cons ?

**Option B**

Is it safe to just leave the field in my `clients` table as `text` and use validations to limit it, by having an `app_settings` area with a hash of what the acceptable values are?

- Pros ?
- Cons ?

**Others**

Are there any other options?

Comment: I've just found a similar question [Rails Models: how would you create a pre-defined set of attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536527/rails-models-how-would-you-create-a-pre-defined-set-of-attributes) which is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the gem [Frozen Record](https://github.com/byroot/frozen_record) :

> ActiveRecord-like interface for read only access to YAML static data.

And define the available titles in YML files.

---

**Or** you could simply set a constant in your model, and validate the inclusion of the title attrbibute in the array you defined:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  TITLES = %w( Mrs M Other ).freeze # same as TITLES = ['Mrs', 'M', 'Other']
  validates :title, presence: true, inclusion: { in: TITLES }
```

You can eventually restrain the user to select only one title in a `select` tag in the form:

```
f.select :title, options_for_select(Client::TITLES)
```

So it won't give an error unless the end-user actually modifies the params sent.

Comment: These days I use a constant in my model. Other scenarios, I use the active_hash gem