# Creating a YAML based list vs. a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, yaml, activemodel

I have an app that consists mainly of restaurant model instances. One of the essential attributes for these restaurants is labeling the **cuisine** it falls under. I'm currently at odds with myself in regards to designing this. On one hand I thought of creating a `Cuisine` model and creating either a `HMT` or `HABTM` association between `Restaurants` and `Cuisines`.

More recently I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6698431/3046413) which shows how to create a pre-defined set of attributes. To take the answer one step further I'm assuming (in my case) I'd add a string-based `cuisine` column to my restaurant model and setup a select box in my restaurant form that would save the selected value.

What I was wondering was what would be the most efficient way of doing this? The goal is to eventually be able to query restaurants based what cuisine(s) they fall under. I wasn't sure if a model would be the best choice due to it only serving as a *join table* in a sense with a `name` attribute. Wasn't sure if having this extra table for something so minute would be optimal.

On the other hand I didn't know if using YAML for this would be conducive since the values are essentially dummy strings with no tangible records on file like I'd have with a model instance. Can someone help me sort out this confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many benefits of normalizing many-to-many relationships in the db. [Here are some](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/databases216.htm):

- Searching, sorting, and creating indexes is faster, since tables are narrower, and more rows fit on a data page.
- You can have more clustered indexes (one per table), so you get more flexibility in tuning queries.
- Index searching is often faster, since indexes tend to be narrower and shorter.
- More tables allow better use of segments to control physical placement of data.
- You usually have fewer indexes per table, so data modification commands are faster.
- Fewer null values and less redundant data, making your database more compact.
- Triggers execute more quickly if you are not maintaining redundant data.
- Data modification anomalies are reduced.
- Normalization is conceptually cleaner and easier to maintain and change as your needs change.

Also, by normalizing you get the cleaner syntax and other infrastructure benefits from ActiveRecord, e.g.

```
cuisine.restaurants.where(city: 'Toledo')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for providing an answer. Going this route would you suggest keeping my cuisines in a seed file? I already have a pre-defined list and don't intend to add many more.

Comment: @CarlEdwards, yes seeds are good for a fixed list. But since cuisines and fusions are being revived and invented all the time, that sounds like a dubious premise. But seeds are also good for seeding the basics of a growing list.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Is there anything extra I have to do to normalize my model or are these the benefits that come with models as is?

Comment: @CarlEdwards, normalizing a database means minimizing data redundancy, keeping it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). The benefits flow from that. Just apply that principle whenever it doesn't cost too much.