# How can I set a series of questions in a rails app across all Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display a series of pre-set questions to all Users of my app. Users are all protected from seeing each other's content using the Hartl "current_user" method/a sessions controller. I need the questions to persist across any app user, and only secure their answers behind the session_controller.

Each question would have_one answer, and the answer_type could be either 1.) a boolean, 2.) a free text field (text_area), 3.) an integer, 4.) Datetime, 5.) an enum (fixed response value e.g. "good", "bad", "indifferent"), 6.) another model object/collection of objects.

Depending on the answer provided, the app should route the user to the next logical question. I was considering using a state_machine to do this, but I think it would be an ugly mess of code to maintain.

Is there a way for me to define a list of questions, hard code the answer_type (I know which answer_type each question will have up front), and define which next_question is displayed depending on the answer provided? (e.g. if "yes" route to question 2, if "no" route to question 8).

I found the following which seems to suggest I could hard-code the questions in a configuration YAML file: [creating a pre-defined set of attributes for a Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536527/rails-models-how-would-you-create-a-pre-defined-set-of-attributes)

I presume I could do the same with an array of information stored in a YAML file - e.g. question, answer_type, next_question_if_yes, next_question_if_no, etc coded into it.

Is there another way for me to assign questions into a Rails app where every account that signs up for the app would have the same questions pre-configured, and the path through those questions would be determined by User answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to create is in a sense a state machine. Imagine a flowchart of how each question will lead to the next.

There are many ways to do it but essentially what happens is that your controller evaluates what stage of the process the current user is in and then presents the next piece of data based on that information.

Your YAML file would be source of the ids of the next questions to go to based on the answer to the current question.

For example, given the following question tree in YAML:

```
# config/initializers/questions.yml
questions:
- id: 1
  question_text: "What is 1+1?"
  answers:
    - answer_text: "2"
      next_question_id: 3
    - answer_text: "3"
      next_question_id: 2
- id: 2
  question_text: "Did you fail math class?"
  answers:
    - answer_text: "yes"
      next_question_id: 3
    - answer_text: "no"
      next_question_id: 1
- id: 3
  question_text: "Who was the first President of the US?"
  answers:
    - answer_text: "George Washington"
      next_question_id: 4
    - answer_text: "Santa Claus"
      next_question_id: 3
```

Then assuming your YAML got loaded into a hash called `QUESTIONS_HASH`, if you had a questions controller in which answers to questions were submitted to a method called `submit_answer`:

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb

...
def submit_answer
  question_id = params[:question_id].to_i
  answer_text = params[:answer]
  current_question = QUESTIONS_HASH["questions"].find {|q| q["id"] == question_id }
  given_answer = current_question.find {|a| a["answer_text"] == answer_text }
  next_question_id = given_answer["next_question_id"]
  @next_question = Question.find_by_id(next_question_id)
  resp = Response.create(user_id: current_user.id, question_id: question_id, answer_text: answer_text)
  resp.save
  current_user.next_question_id = next_question_id
  redirect_to questions_path

def index
    @question = Question.find_by_id(current_user.next_question_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jess, that's definitely what I'm trying to build here. I presume in my question controller I'd also need a way to identify the different answer_types and present the right answer model. I also need a method to head back "up" the state_machine, so if a user gets more information and can answer earlier questions differently, they then get presented a new branch of questions.

Comment: Yeah, if each question has an `answer_type` key, then you can use that value to display the right kinds of HTML (selects, checkboxes, etc.). To move up the state_machine you'd probably want to have some listing of all questions asked so far and then just let the user select an old question to go to and then it will continue on from there as desired.

Comment: Thanks Jess - I'll have a play around and see what I can describe in the YAML file.

Comment: Hi Jess, one other thing. In some situations I'll need to loop through the same set of questions more than once (imagine I'm asking do you have friends> yes > what's their name > input name > do you have other friends? > yes > loop back to what's their name etc.) - any idea how I'd configure that in this setup?

Comment: Define 1 new parameter for each question called `collectable` and if it's true then the collectable questions like "what's your other friend's name?" will be combined with a other answers collected for that collection. How do you identify collections? Give special questions a `collection_id`. The collection can be an array of string answers, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jess - that's a helpful way of looking at it.