# Is it possible to set a flexible data type using Rails and Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm setting up a question and answer model, and some questions will require Boolean answers, some will require Text, some Integers, some enum (I guess that's the same as integer, but I need to define the meaning in the model) and some Datetime). Is it possible for me to set a flexible model column in the Answer model (e.g. one answer column that accepts any data, and only sets it according to the answer_type of a question object)? Or would it be better to set up a YesNoAnswer model, a TextAnswer model, an IntegerAnswer model etc etc, and then a method on the Question model that chooses which type of answer model it needs based on the answer_type column?

For what it's worth I'm planning to load pre-set questions into the DB using a YAML file that "know" what next_question to send the controller to depending on the answer to the previous question. See my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586822/how-can-i-set-a-series-of-questions-in-a-rails-app-across-all-users/34587354?noredirect=1#comment56920069_34587354).

I had heard about variant data types, but I'm not sure whether that's possible with Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) to list out the data types which were using in rails, btw, [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE) lists out all postgres's data types, likely, we don't have what you expected.

My experience in a previous project to work with multiple data types is:

> 1. Define a `value` column (type is text, so it is enough to contain anything)
> 2. Define a `value_type` column (this is an enum: {:integer, :boolean,..} for eg)
> 3. Define validation callbacks to validate the `value` & `value_type`

Hope this helps for you